# from Qgis 2.2 to Garmin Base Camp: how to get rid of the white frame?

Tags: qgis, export, garmin

I have geo-referenced a raster map in QGIS 2.2 (with the georeferencer plugin) and I can also create a kmz file for my garmin (Dakota20) with GarminustomMap. However the kmz file, as imported in Base Camp, has a white frame around and in spite of many trials (change transparency, change file type both in input and output, clip a portion to have a straight map etc etc) I couldn't  avoid that. This seems to be the white border around the image appearing in Qgis.
I have been googling for dayds, but I didn't find anything.
I am a beginner, please can you help?
Many many thanks
Carla

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to add the white colour as an transparent pixel colour in QGIS. To do this, double click the georeferenced raster layer, and select the "Transparency" tab. There's a button to the right of this tab for "Add values from display" (looks like a pointer with a blue question mark behind it). Click this, then click somewhere on the white border part of your georeferenced layer. Click OK - the white portion will now be transparent in QGIS.

The second step is to export the layer with this transparency from QGIS. This is done by right-clicking the layer in the layer panel, and choose "Save as". Change the output mode to "Rendered Image" - this will keep the white color as transparent pixels. Then, click "Browse", choose an output filename, and click OK. QGIS will save the georeferenced raster image complete with the transparent border to your destination.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work in my case. I followed your instruction though. First problem: when I try to "add value from display" on the white border the program does nothing at all when I click (it works inside the tilted map but not outside). What I did was to add by hand a value 255,255,255 with 100% transparency. However I get the same as before.